# count() results in NAN

Tags: javascript, count

I do this simple thing:

```
var aantalPaginas = element.all(by.xpath('//nav/ul/li')).count();
console.log(aantalPaginas);
```

Why does this result in NaN? I want to have a number.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to count?

Comment: You should take a look at the synthax on the [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_examples.asp) this may help you out.

Comment: the problem is: the count() function results in a 'promise' and i want to solve that promise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protractor returning a value from a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31780731/protractor-returning-a-value-from-a-promise)