# Protractor returning a value from a promise

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, protractor

I'm writing a test to see if my code is removing a level by looking at a text value on the screen which holds the count of levels.

```
  it 'allows deleting level versions', ->
    browser.get('/api#/costings')
    element(By.id("edit")).click()
    startCount = element(By.id("versions_count")).getText().then( (count) ->
      return count
    )

    element(By.id("versions")).click()
    first=element.all(By.id("listing")).first()
    first.element(By.id("delete")).click()
    helper.accept_dialog()

    element(By.id("back")).click()
    expect(element(By.id("versions_count")).getText()).toEqual(startCount - 1)
```

Problem here is startCount results in a function. I cannot seem to get startCount into an integer so that I can see if the count has gone down by 1 item.

It gives me the error;

```
  1) edit an existing costing allows deleting level versions
   Message:
     Expected '1' to equal NaN.
```

If I try parseInt(startCount) I get the same error.

Comment: What is your startCount . From where are you getting it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `startCount` is a promise, and so `startCount - 1` doesn't make sense: there is no automatic type conversion from a promise to its resolved value, so you can't subtract one from it.

What you can do, is create a promise whose resolved value is the expected versions count:

```
expectedCount = element(By.id("versions_count")).getText().then( (count) ->
  return (count - 1).toString();
)
```

and then you can pass this promise to `toEqual`, as it automatically unwraps promises at the appropriate point in the control flow

```
expect(element(By.id("versions_count")).getText()).toEqual(expectedCount)
```

Comment: Now I get Expected '1' to equal 1, if I try and use parseInt on the getText part I get NaN to equal { then : Function, cancel : Function, isPending : Function }, if I try and use toString() on the expectedCount I get '1' to equal '[object Object]'

Comment: @map7 I've edited the answer that addresses that issue (exactly as your edit suggested, but was already rejected by other reviewers)

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any other way of doing this. Seems like if you try to change int to string or string to int anywhere else in that code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
it("Verify Add Element", function(){
        basePage.gotoAssetsPage();
        var numberOfElementsBefore = assetsPage.getTotalAssertsNumber();//get text from counter
        assetsPage.createAsset(); // add one object on the page
        var numberOfElementsAfter = assetsPage.getTotalAssertsNumber(); // get text from counter after creation of object

        numberOfElementsBefore.then(function(startNumberText) {
            console.log("Number of Asserts before test is " + startNumberText);
            return startNumberText;
        });
        numberOfElementsAfter.then(function(endNumberText) {
            console.log("Number of Asserts after test is " + endNumberText);
            expect(assertsBefore).toBe((endNumberText-1).toString());
        });   
    });
```

In this test I'm verifying, that quantity of elements before text will equals quantity of elements after test minus 1. 
If I not use .toString(), test result will be: **Expect '21' to be 21**. So, converting to string works. Maybe someone have a better solution :)